# Define a cube root function in METAPOST

Tags: metapost

I want to draw the graph of the cube root function $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x+1}$ by using METAPOST. However, when I use the vardef macro as follows

```
vardef f(expr x) = (x+1)**(1/3) enddef;
```

It seems to be invalid. How can we define this function in METAPOST?

Comment: You don't say what is invalid, but clearly, the definition `vardef f(expr x) = (x+1)**(1/3) enddef;` does define a macro corresponding to the function `x\mapsto \sqrt[3]{x+1}`. For instance, `f(2)` is `1.44225`, which is a good approximation of the cubic root of 3.

Comment: I'm so sorry for this confusion. The reason is that I want to draw this function's graph, e.g. when x run from -5 to 5. I think that METAPOST does not understand f(-5) because the exponential function defined with positive values of x. Thus, I want to know is there any way in METAPOST to define a cube root function? The square root function in METAPOST is sqrt(x) but sqrt[3](x) is invalid.

Answer (score 4):

According to [your comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536255/define-a-cube-root-function-in-metapost?noredirect=1#comment1354733_536255), the part you needed help for  was to have the cube root work even for negative numbers. What about this?

```
vardef cuberoot(expr x) = if x < 0: -1* fi ((abs(x))**(1/3)) enddef;
vardef f(expr x) = cuberoot(x+1) enddef;

show f(-1);
show f(2);
show f(1);
show f(-3);

end
```

Output:

```
>> 0
>> 1.44225
>> 1.25992
>> -1.25992
```

Note: instead of `if x < 0: -1* fi`, you can also use `if x < 0: - fi` (it is possibly a tiny bit faster).

Comment: It is absolutely wonderful. Thank you so much for your instruction.

Comment: Glad to hear that. My MetaPost-fu is a bit rusty these days, but I still remember a few things. :-)